# “Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined” in android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, dictionary

java script code

> var myMap = new Map();

In chrome browser, works well, but in android browser throw “Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined”.
Anyway to enable it on Android browser or I need to change my code and not using map in order the code will work on all browsers? 
And Are there any other browsers this error can happen?

Comment: `Map` is a part of ES6. If your browser doesn't support ES6, it wouldn't support `Map` either.

Comment: See compatibility table - http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks a million! You saved me!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks a million! You saved me!